Why did the third doctor never meet the cybermen?
It is well known that Jon Pertwee disliked the Daleks. Indeed, in a 1982 interview with Debbie Fisher on Two Counties Radio (2CR), Pertwee both derided their design and did not understand how they became popular.
In spite of this, the Third Doctor met them three times.
However, it is notable that during his tenure, the Third Doctor never met the Cybermen.
A Cyberman did appear in the episode "Carnival of Monsters", but it isn't obvious that he was aware of this when he arranged everything transported back to their original space and time coordinates. As well, he did meet the Cybermen in he "Five Doctors".
Is it known if there is a particular reason Pertwee never met the Cybermen, they were at the time a popular monster that practically every other Doctor has met (not including the Eighth since he only appeared in the film, and the Ninth Doctor possibly left earlier than he would have liked, see this link)?

Something something licencing. Before the modern era, when rights to characters tended to revert to the studio, scriptwriters could essentially veto the use of their creations

Reddit - Why was there little to no cybermen in the 70s?
